# python django email set correct sender gunicorn

Tags: python, django

This is my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' # mail service smtp
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xx@xx.com' # email id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sdjlfkjdskjfdsjkjfkds' #password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'xx@xx.com'
```

I am sending password reset email
It works fine on localhost but on production server as sender I get webmaster@localhost

What do I do?

This is my urls.py

```
 url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset.html',
        email_template_name = 'accounts/email/password_reset.html',
        html_email_template_name = 'accounts/email/password_reset.html',
        subject_template_name = 'accounts/email/password_reset_subject.html'),
```

Comment: Have you authorised less secure apps on your gmail account that you using to send emails ?

Comment: @KeshavGarg yes.

Comment: Can you show up your code where you are sending automated email ?

Comment: @KeshavGarg django is sending them automatically, see my urls.py in the updated code

Comment: Try logging `settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` somewhere. Maybe your settings aren't being read for some reasons

Comment: Do you happen to overwrite your `settings.py` in your production deployment, or add a `localsettings.py` that could override some variables?

Answer (score 2):

First I want to explain why you get specifically **webmaster@localhost** email.

### Explanation

django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm.save() function uses None as a from email address, **webmaster@localhost** is used by default, so you should just need to add **DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL** property to your settings.py.

### Solution

Connect to your production enviroment and run the django shell with `python manage.py shell`.

Now run the following commands.

```
# Check your enviroment, should say something like production.
import os
os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')

# Check if the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL property is set.
from django.conf import settings
settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
```

With `os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')` you will get the settings file you are using for production, so if `settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` isn't set just edit that file and add it with your email.

### Recomendations

Use another email backend (mandrill, sendgrid, etc...) to ensure that your mails will reach the inbox and not the spam folder.

For this you can use [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) package.

### References

[How to create a password reset view in Django - simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html)